# Opening a ECSlidingViewController from a non ECSlidingViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, sliding

I have tried reaching a ECSlidingViewController on IBAction. However when I tried the below code:

```
-(IBAction)openNewPage:(id)sender{ //IV

UIStoryboard *storyboard;
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IV"];
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
}

slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTop"];

}
```

I get the following error:

```
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

I tried a modal action on the button, the 'touchupinside' will land at the InitialViewController. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the line where you define slidingViewController to below your if-else-if clause because storyboard will be nil where you currently do it.

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone" bundle:nil];
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
}
ECSlidingViewController *slidingViewController = (ECSlidingViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IV"];
slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstTop"];
```

Comment: In this case, I passed the modal action to the initial view controller which is blank. As a result I get a blank page. If I pass it to the top view controller I get the error again. Any idea on how to go about this? thanks for the help

Comment: @SiddharthanAsokan, I have no idea what you're talking about without seeing more code. What modal action? What is the initial view controller? If you log slidingViewController using the code I gave you , does it log correctly?